# JQuery date picker does not set hidden field value in asp.net webform

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, hidden-field

Within a webform I have a jquery datepicker that is bound to text field in the ui which in turn is bound to a hidden field  (asp hidden field not html)

```
<div class="dateContainer">
     <span class="fbSmallLabel">Start Date</span>
        <input id="txtStartDate" class="datequeryterm" type="text" value="<%= ((HiddenField)Parent.FindControl("hdnStartDate")).Value %>" />
 </div>
```

When a date is selected the hndfield is updated which then updates the value in the textbox

```
$("#btnApplyFilter").click(function () {
        setFilterFields();
        $.modal.close();
    }); 

function setFilterFields() {       
        var startDate = $("#txtStartDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#txtEndDate").val();

        $("#hdnStartDate").val(startDate);
        $("#hdnEndDate").val(endDate);
    }
```

Using firebug or IE dev tools I can see that the hidden field is updated in the DOM however when I reference the hidden field from the webform I get a null "" value.

```
protected void SetSearchFilterData()
{
   DateTime dt;
   string StartDate = hdnStartDate.Value;
   string EndDate = hdnEndDate.Value;

   if (DateTime.TryParse(StartDate, out dt))
   {           
     srchRequest.DateRangeStart = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
   }

   if (DateTime.TryParse(EndDate, out dt))
   {   
     srchRequest.DateRangeEnd = DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
   }
}
```

The method is a bit basic as I was trying to explicitly see what was happening with the variable assignment. 
Previously I was declaring the start date and end date in the following manner

```
public string StartDate
{
  get { return hdnStartDate.Value; }
  set { hdnStartDate.Value = value; }
}
```

While this did detect the field the value continues to be null.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

-cheers

Comment: Could the hidden field values be getting reset on pageLoad?

Comment: @JoshMein No. that is what I thought but in looking at firebug that is not the case I can see the values once they are applied and they are not being reset. However when called from the webform on a click event the value is null but just for the date. the other hidden fields retain their values.

Answer (score 0):

The one `input` tag you posted has no `name` so it won't submit any form data

Comment: The input he posted was not one of his hidden fields.

Comment: @JoshMein good possibility the hidden one doesn't hav a name either

Comment: If the hidden field did not have it then how would he be grabbing the control on server side? It would throw an error. He hasn't mentioned anything about an error being thrown.

Comment: The input tag is passing its values to the asp:hidden field through JavaScript (second snippet). The input tag is not referenced in code behind. The hidden field is an asp.net hidden control. It's Id is the hdnstartdate or hdnenddate selector listed above. Both of those can be referenced from code